# Question regarding scope of variables/environment variables in Linux

Tags: linux, shell, environment-variables

I would like to get a better understanding about the theorical/technical reason of the following behaviour

On a Linux shell I run the following:

```
MY_VAR="foo" && python3 -c "import os; print('MY_VAR' in os.environ)"
```

And the result is False

I understand that this is due to the fact that in order to access a variable from a subprocess of the current shell (In this case Python), we need to export it, so when running like this

```
EXPORT MY_VAR="foo" && python3 -c "import os; print('MY_VAR' in os.environ)"
```

Result is True

I know this also happens with bash scripts that we call from terminal, in order for the script to have access to the variable it needs to be exported before

However when running something like the following:

```
MY_VAR_2="foo_2" && echo "This line matches foo_2" | grep ${MY_VAR_2} | wc -l
```

Result is 1 so there is match

My question is, in this case why MY_VAR_2 was "available" to grep with no need of using EXPORT ?
Isn't grep also a program and therefore a subprocess of the existing shell ?

Comment: Please don't abuse `&&` like that. It's completely pointless.

Answer (score 2):

With:

```
MY_VAR_2="foo_2" && echo "This line matches foo_2" | grep ${MY_VAR_2} | wc -l
```

You are executing commands in the same shell and hence the variable MY_VAR_2 will be available to all commands

If you change the line to:

```
MY_VAR_2="foo_2" && bash -c 'echo "This line matches foo_2"' | bash -c 'grep ${MY_VAR_2} | wc -l'
```

Because separate shells are opened, the variable will no longer be available unless you use export and so:

```
export MY_VAR_2="foo_2" && bash -c 'echo "This line matches foo_2"' | bash -c 'grep ${MY_VAR_2} | wc -l'
```

In the case of python, you will in effect be opening an new shell and so the same logic applies.

Comment: Is there an easy way to know which commands run in a new shell and which not ?

Comment: @DavidFliguer, In your first example involving `grep` it doesn't matter that command is not a shell builtin. That's because the shell in which you defined the var performs the expansion of `${MY_VAR_2}` and passes that value to the program. In your other examples the use of single-quoted strings keeps the current shell from expanding the var reference. Try those commands using a double-quoted string.

Comment: @KurtisRader I do not use single quotes in my example, all the quotes are double

Raman example used single quote and that is the reason for different behavior